# How do I aggregate 1 minute data into 15 minutes

Tags: r, split

I have 1 minute data, I was wondering how do I aggregate (split) it into 15 minute data in R. I am using Rstudio user interface.

```
head(FW20_1min)
                    Open High  Low Close Volume
2010-04-19 08:31:00 2536 2537 2531  2532   2459
2010-04-19 08:32:00 2532 2535 2531  2533    625
2010-04-19 08:33:00 2532 2534 2531  2534    405
2010-04-19 08:34:00 2534 2535 2534  2534    179
2010-04-19 08:35:00 2534 2536 2534  2535    217
2010-04-19 08:36:00 2535 2536 2534  2534    162
```

The structure of the data is :

```
str(FW20_1min)
An ‘xts’ object on 2010-04-19 08:31:00/2010-04-19 16:30:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:465, 1:5] 2536 2532 2532 2534 2534 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXlt,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

The `dput()` is:

```
dput(head(FW20_1min))
structure(c(2536, 2532, 2532, 2534, 2534, 2535, 2537, 2535, 2534, 
2535, 2536, 2536, 2531, 2531, 2531, 2534, 2534, 2534, 2532, 2533, 
2534, 2534, 2535, 2534, 2459, 625, 405, 179, 217, 162), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(1271658660, 
1271658720, 1271658780, 1271658840, 1271658900, 1271658960), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", 
"High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"))
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(head(FW20_1min))`.  It sort of looks like an `xts` object which would make this very easy

Answer (score 1):

```
split(FW20_1min, "minutes", k=15)
```

or

```
to.period(FW20_1min, "minutes", 15) # or to.minutes15(FW20_1min)
```

depending on what you want to do

Comment: I need to calculate returns for close prices at 1 min interval and 15 minute interval.

Comment: `ROC(Cl(FW20_1min), n=15)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I wrote the question quite clear but I do not know why I received two negative votes.

Comment: "aggregate", "split", and "calculate returns" are 3 completely different things (i.e. not clear), all three of which are pretty basic... (i.e. lacking research effort, which is one of the reasons to downvote -- hover the mouse over the downvote button to see)

Comment: I see, thank you very.I did know how to calculate return I just needed to split the data.

Comment: Which was the answer I gave, but then you said you needed to calculate returns, and as you can see, there's no need to split the data if all you're doing is calculating returns.